# Heap sort and Quick sort stability

Tags: algorithm, sorting, stability

i had tried with array that have **2 or 3 elements equal**,of course it's **not stable** but if we have array that have all element equal like this `[2,2,2,2,2,2,2]` will it be **stable or not** ?
of course by using heap sort or quick sort.

thanks.

Comment: Depends on your definition - you could even claim that a random shuffle was stable for this input.

Answer (score 0):

Stability for given data set depends on implementation details. For example, look at Lomuto partition from [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

```
algorithm partition(A, lo, hi) is
    pivot := A[hi]
    i := lo - 1    
    for j := lo to hi - 1 do
        if A[j] < pivot then
            i := i + 1
            swap A[i] with A[j]
    swap A[i + 1] with A[hi]
    return i + 1
```

We can see that `i` never increments, so last swap exchanges the first and the last items of range, breaking initial order.

Hoare partition implementation from the same page seems doesn't break order